# Angularjs: why is the parent to the scope necessary?

Tags: angularjs

Controller:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('browse', [])

    .controller('browseCtrl', ['$scope', 'exchangesFctr', function($scope, exchangesFctr) {

        // exchanges
        $scope.exchanges = exchangesFctr.get();
        $scope.exchange = null;
        $scope.$watch('exchange', function() {
            console.info('EXCHANGE', $scope.exchange);
        });

        // sectors
        $scope.sector = null;
    }]);
```

exchanges partial:

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-controller="browseCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn" btn-radio="exchange" ng-model="$parent.exchange"
            ng-repeat="exchange in exchanges | orderBy:exchange.name">{{ exchange.name }}</button>
</div>
    <ng-include src="'browse/sectors.html'" />
```

sectors partial:

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-controller="browseCtrl" ng-hide="$parent.exchange == null">
    <p>todo</p>
</div>
```

1) Using ui.bootstrap: why on the exchanges partial is the ng-model required to bind to the parent to work? I expected this to be `ng-model="exchange"`? Am I doing something wrong here?

2) On the sectors partial the `ng-hide` only executes once. I expected the expression to update when the `$scope.exchange` is changed. What expression must I use for it to be always up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with UI Bootstrap . This is happening because of normal javascript prototype behaviour . If you use primitive types then you have to use $parent otherwise if you switch to object syntax than there is no need to use $parent see below sample code

$scope.exchange = {name:null};

Then the html should be ng-model="exchange.name" (no need to use parent if you want on objects instead of primitives)

The url shall explain you everything in detail https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Thanks; any suggestions for the ng-hide binding?

Comment: your expression for ng-hide seems to be fine i dont see any issue in this

Comment: Why isn't `$parent` then used in the buttons radiomodel example? http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons

Comment: you include your view without ng-include and everything will work with $parent and even on primitive types but if you include your view inside ng-include then you have to either use $parent or object watching because  ng-include creates a new scope which inherits from parent scope . The example mentioned on the site does not use ng-include you remove your ng-include from you app and it will work like example